# Question in Proof of Riemann's theorem on removable singularities

Tags: complex-analysis

I have this from Shakarchi, in the proof of the 'Riemann's theorem on removable singularities. He states the following:

[image: page1].
He uses the following contour:
[image: page2]

and comes to the following conclusions about the smaller circle containing $z_{o}$
[image: page3]
and so on. About the second integral he says:

[image: page4]

How is he arriving that the bounds is $\leq C\epsilon$?

Comment: What "Shakarchi"? He has several books...

Comment: Stein and Shakarchi - complex analysis @DonAntonio

Answer (score 2):

That's the [Estimation Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_lemma) , with $\;M\;$ being the bound of $\;|f(z)|\;$ in some neighborhood if $\;z\;$:

$$\left|\int_{\gamma_\epsilon}\frac{f(\zeta}{\zeta-z}d\zeta\right|\le \max_{\zeta\in\gamma_\epsilon'}\frac{|f(\zeta)|}{|\zeta-z|}\cdot\ell(\gamma_\epsilon
')\le \frac M{R}2\pi \epsilon $$

and now denote $\;C=2\frac MR\pi\;$ and we're done. It is unfortunate, if I understand correctly what is going on in that proof, the use of $\;C\;$ for the above bound *and also* for the boundary circle...

Comment: Indeed  @DonAntonio! I would champion for a change in the text.

Answer (score 1):

Let $M=\min\{|\zeta-z|:\zeta\in \gamma_{\varepsilon}'\}>0.$ Then
$$\left|\int_{\gamma_{\varepsilon}'}\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-z}d\zeta\right|\leq \frac{M_1}{M}2\pi\varepsilon=C\varepsilon,$$
where $M_1$ is the constant satisfying $|f(\zeta)|\leq M_1$ for $\zeta\in\gamma_{\varepsilon}'$.